# get ipv4 packet header from boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, nat

I have a problem.
How can I get ipv4 paket header from boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket?
Is it possible?

I'm writing a simple realisation of NAT service for sql traffic, getting from clients by server.
Server is based on boost::asio example code structure [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp).

And I want to resend packets, which my server gets from clients to mmssql server. And do the same while getting answers from mssql server.

I want to edit packet header directly, as it NAT service does, (may be there is another way? :)) by changing source ip to ip of this server, and destination ip to ip of mssql server. And do similar things in reverse direction (from mssql to client).

What can you advice for me?

Comment: tcp sockets strip the header. raw sockets give you the whole packet.

Comment: <strike>I don't think Asio is your library then</strike> Aw blimey! A 5 second google later: https://github.com/kevincon/asio-rawsockets-example

Comment: I know about raw sockets here: github.com/kevincon/asio-rawsockets-example
But i don't know how can i use it for reading purposes:
Can you show me example of ACCEPTING connections on this socket? :) Because my server accepts connection on tcp sockets, and it can't accepting connections on raw sockets (there is no method async_accept into boost::asio::ip::tcp::accceptor, first parameter of which is raw socket)